# How can I use friendly ID in Rails like mysite.com/[USERNAME]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, friendly-id

How can I use friendly URLs on my Rails application ?
All I need is to make available the following url format

mysite.com/company1
mysite.com/user123
mysite.com/user1234
mysite.com/newton.garcia
mysite.com/company-name

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4):

I already ask this question on Quora..

http://www.quora.com/How-does-Quora-rewrite-their-urls

For who really interested to implement Quora/Facebook URLs like.
Heres a tip in Rails3:

Make a table called `slugs` :

```
#  slug | model_id |  model
# ===========================
# simple data:
#  one  |    2222    |  post
#  two  |    1111    |  user
#  six   |    5432    |  comment
```

Now in routes.rb add this line to the bottom:

```
match '/:id', :to => proc { |env|
  id = env["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"][:id]
  model = Slug.find_by_slug(id).model
  controller = [model.pluralize.camelize,"Controller"].join.constantize
  controller.action("show").call(env)
}, :as => :slugable
```

so, if we go to `/one` in the routes, it translated to be:

```
id: one
so from the slugs table,
model: post
and the route will point to "posts#show"
```

Now in the `show` action in all controllers

```
@something = Model.find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem called [SubDomain-Fu](http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu) for this. Watch this [screen cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains) for more details.

Comment: Is it the best way to do it ?
What I want is to make available USER unique URL's like Facebook.

facebook.com/newtongarcia
facebook.com/username1
facebook.com/username2

Comment: The screen cast linked in my answer has a similar use case as yours. Watch it for more details.