# Edit in nested routes with no paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested, friendly-id

Using: Rails 3.1.1 and Friendly_id for url's.

I think this should be fairly easy but I can't figure it out.

I have a nested route that looks like this:

```
  resources :pages, :path => '' do
    # WHAT_DO_I_TYPE_HERE
    resources :products, :except => [:index], :path => '' do
        member do
            post 'broken_link'
        end
    end    
  end
```

Where the unmarked (#) line is the one I am trying to figure out. Basically I have urls that look like this:

domain.com/page_name/product_name/ (through friendly_id's), e.g. domain.com/music/mp3/.

**I want to use the url domain.com/music/edit to edit the page about music.**

Now, if I type:
a. `<blank>`   # i.e. nothing...leave that line blank
--- I get the error "Couldn't find Product with id=edit" which makes sense in a way. It tries to find a PRODUCT called edit not the method edit. So instead I try
b. match 'edit', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'edit'
--- which gives  me the error 'Couldn't find Page without an ID' which, I guess, makes sense as well.

So what should I write to tell the routes to check for the edit method before checking for a product name?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before ... 
There are a few things you can do to achieve the url routing you want  ...

Firstly, with the code you have there, I would suggest taking a look at what `rake routes` in the command line produces for anything relating to page_path or page_product / product_page paths and see what urls it catches + their named routes.

If it's not quite what you want .. then you could try putting:

```
get '/:id' => 'products#show'
```

in place of your `# WHAT_DO_I_TYPE_HERE`

Although, you may need to put a constraint on that (see links at the bottom) so that you can still have your `/mypage/edit` and `mypage/new` etc ...

What you really want to do is set up a route that looks like this:

```
match '/:page_id/:id' => 'products#show', :as => 'product'
```

This should go somewhere above these routes and will be available via the `product_show_path`. This assumes you're using a standard has/belongs to relationship.

You can rename the `:as => 'product'` portion to whatever you want,

eg: `:as => 'public_product'`

Then update your links to show public_products_path where needed

In your products#show action you should then do:

```
@product = Product.find(:id => params[:id], :page_id => params[:page_id])
```

you could also look at putting constraints on the routes ...
I have put together a Gist for my own reference here that might be useful to you.
https://gist.github.com/1908782

Also, I came across this answer to another question which might help you too ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443829/308701

Hope that helps in some way :D